# How do I add a column to a pyspark dataframe with the timestamp of the minimum value over a window?

Tags: pyspark

Say I have a pyspark dataframe such as:

| Timestamp | Foo |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-12-02T10:00:00 | 12 |
| 2022-12-02T10:01:00 | 24 |
| 2022-12-02T10:02:00 | 26 |
| 2022-12-02T10:03:00 | 20 |
| 2022-12-02T10:04:00 | 31 |
| 2022-12-02T10:05:00 | 30 |
| 2022-12-02T10:06:00 | 23 |
| 2022-12-02T10:07:00 | 35 |
| 2022-12-02T10:08:00 | 10 |
| 2022-12-02T10:09:00 | 20 |
| 2022-12-02T10:10:00 | 40 |

I add a column 'min_value', being the minimum value of the column 'Foo' in a five minutes backwards window, as:

```
window_bw = Window.orderBy(F.col('timestamp').cast('int')).rangeBetween(-5*60, 0)

df = df.withColumn('min_value', F.min('Foo').over(window_backwards))
```

That is easy enough, but I cannot figure out how to add another column "min_value_timestamp" which is the timestamp of the row 'min_value' was taken from.

I tried using when like this:

```
df = (df.withColumn('min_value_timestamp', F.when(F.col('Foo') == F.col('min_value'), F.col('timestamp')) 
        .withColumn('min_value_timestamp', F.when(F.last('min_value_timestamp', ignorenulls = True).over(window_bw)))
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work, because a certain row may not have the minimum value for its own window, but have the minimum value for the window of a later row. So in the example dataframe the first six rows get the correct 'min_value_timestamp', but the seventh row would get 'min_value_timestamp' null, since it's calculated in parallel and all rows in the window have 'min_value_timestamp' null at that point (and even if it wasn't, it wouldn't matter anyhow since it would be the wrong timestamp. Row four's min_value and corresponding min_value_timestamp comes from row one in its window, but row 4 is also where the min_value of rows 7 and 8 comes from, so they should have the timestamp of row 4 as 'min_value_timestamp', which wouldn't work with the logic above).

Does anyone know a way to do it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine time and value into a struct then collect within the window and sort them by value then extract value of first element of list.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

data = [[f'2022-12-03 00:{"%.2d" % i}:00', random.randint(0, 30)] for i in range(20)]
df = (
    spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = ['time', 'value'])
    .withColumn('timestamp', F.unix_timestamp('time'))
)

window = W.orderBy(F.col('timestamp').cast('int')).rangeBetween(-5*60, 0)
(
    df
    .withColumn('past_values', F.collect_list(F.struct('value', 'time')).over(window))
    .withColumn('min_value', F.sort_array('past_values')[0]['time'])
).show()

+-------------------+-----+----------+--------------------+-------------------+
|               time|value| timestamp|         past_values|          min_value|
+-------------------+-----+----------+--------------------+-------------------+
|2022-12-03 00:00:00|   29|1670013000|[{29, 2022-12-03 ...|2022-12-03 00:00:00|
|2022-12-03 00:01:00|   23|1670013060|[{29, 2022-12-03 ...|2022-12-03 00:01:00|
|2022-12-03 00:02:00|   29|1670013120|[{29, 2022-12-03 ...|2022-12-03 00:01:00|
|2022-12-03 00:03:00|    6|1670013180|[{29, 2022-12-03 ...|2022-12-03 00:03:00|
|2022-12-03 00:04:00|   26|1670013240|[{29, 2022-12-03 ...|2022-12-03 00:03:00|
|2022-12-03 00:05:00|    1|1670013300|[{29, 2022-12-03 ...|2022-12-03 00:05:00|
|2022-12-03 00:06:00|    1|1670013360|[{23, 2022-12-03 ...|2022-12-03 00:05:00|
|2022-12-03 00:07:00|   14|1670013420|[{29, 2022-12-03 ...|2022-12-03 00:05:00|
|2022-12-03 00:08:00|   16|1670013480|[{6, 2022-12-03 0...|2022-12-03 00:05:00|
|2022-12-03 00:09:00|   19|1670013540|[{26, 2022-12-03 ...|2022-12-03 00:05:00|
|2022-12-03 00:10:00|   29|1670013600|[{1, 2022-12-03 0...|2022-12-03 00:05:00|
|2022-12-03 00:11:00|    1|1670013660|[{1, 2022-12-03 0...|2022-12-03 00:06:00|
|2022-12-03 00:12:00|   15|1670013720|[{14, 2022-12-03 ...|2022-12-03 00:11:00|
|2022-12-03 00:13:00|   22|1670013780|[{16, 2022-12-03 ...|2022-12-03 00:11:00|
|2022-12-03 00:14:00|   11|1670013840|[{19, 2022-12-03 ...|2022-12-03 00:11:00|
|2022-12-03 00:15:00|    9|1670013900|[{29, 2022-12-03 ...|2022-12-03 00:11:00|
|2022-12-03 00:16:00|   30|1670013960|[{1, 2022-12-03 0...|2022-12-03 00:11:00|
|2022-12-03 00:17:00|   28|1670014020|[{15, 2022-12-03 ...|2022-12-03 00:15:00|
|2022-12-03 00:18:00|   30|1670014080|[{22, 2022-12-03 ...|2022-12-03 00:15:00|
|2022-12-03 00:19:00|    4|1670014140|[{11, 2022-12-03 ...|2022-12-03 00:19:00|
+-------------------+-----+----------+--------------------+-------------------+
```